# subprocess.call() to remove files

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to remove all the files and directories except for some of them by using

```
`subprocess.call(['rm','-r','!(new_models|creat_model.py|my_mos.tit)'])`
```

but it gives back information

> rm: cannot remove `!(new_models|creat_model.py|my_mos.tit)': No such file or directory

how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a file or a directory named `!(new_models|creat_model.py|my_mos.tit)`?

Comment: in bash I think this means the files i don't want to remove

Comment: You're right, but with your python line, you don't run a `bash` to interpret this syntax ; you directly create a process running the `rm` program.

Comment: ok, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

If you use that `rm` command on the command line the `!(…|…|…)` pattern is expanded by the shell into all file names except those in the pattern *before* calling `rm`.  Your code calls `rm` directly so `rm` gets the shell pattern as a file name and tries to delete a file with *that* name.

You have to add `shell=True` to the argument list of `subprocess.call()` or actually code this in Python instead of calling external commands.  Downside: That would be more than one line.  Upside: it can be done independently from external shells and system dependent external programs.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `shell=True` could be the usage of `glob` and manual filtering:

```
import glob
files = [i for i in glob.glob("*") if i not in ('new_models', 'creat_model.py', 'my_mos.tit')]
subprocess.call(['rm','-r'] + files)
```

Edit 4 years later:

Without glob (of which I don't remember why I suggested it):

```
import os
files = [i for i in os.listdir() if i not in ('new_models', 'creat_model.py', 'my_mos.tit')]
subprocess.call(['rm','-r'] + files)
```

Comment: I don't see the reason for `glob()` here when you don't actually use `glob()` to filter names.  It's just like calling `os.listdir()` but with more overhead.

Comment: @BlackJack You are completely right. Alas, I don't remember why I did  this at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Code to remove all png

```
args = ('rm', '-rf', '/path/to/files/temp/*.png')

subprocess.call('%s %s %s' % args, shell=True)
```